# How can I translate this syntax to CoffeeScript (js2coffee doesn't work)?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Basically I need to translate the following piece of JavaScript into CoffeeScript.

```
location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    notifyBackground(collectData());
    return undefined;
  };
} + "){}";
```

The return "undefined" is important because the browser will ask the user to confirm that they want to leave the page if I remove it.

You might be wondering wtf I'm doing. Basically, it's a [location hack for Firefox extension development](http://goo.gl/D7DbT).

I've tried doing the following:

```
location.href = "javascript:(" + ->
  window.onbeforeunload = ->
    notifyBackground(collectData())
    return undefined
+ ")()"
```

But that turns into:

```
location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
  return window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    notifyBackground(collectData());
    return void 0;
  };
};
return +")()";
```

Using [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org) gives me this:

```
location.href = "javascript:(" + ->
  window.onbeforeunload = ->
    notifyBackground collectData()
    "undefined"
 + "){}"
```

If I run that through CoffeeScript I get this JS output (which is wrong).

```
location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
  return window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    notifyBackground(collectData());
    return "undefined";
  };
};
return +"){}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this close enough?

```
location.href = "javascript:(#{-> 
  window.onbeforeunload = -> 
    notifyBackground(collectData())
    `undefined`
  return
}){}"
```

Compiles to:

```
location.href = "javascript:(" + (function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    notifyBackground(collectData());
    return undefined;
  };
}) + "){}";
```

Note the backticks around the undefined to avoid the `void 0`, just in case that makes a difference (And I'm not sure if it does?)

### EDIT

In the Chrome console `undefined == void 0` is `true`, so maybe the

```
`undefined`
```

could simply be:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://js2coffee.org/) site http://js2coffee.org/ its a js to coffee (and backwards) converter.

Comment: ... which gives a similar answer to your first attempt, but without the `return undefined`.

Comment: But then if you run the output from js2coffee.org through the CoffeeScript interpreter it comes out with the JS code I have at the bottom of my question. Also the `return "undefined"` is important because the browser will as the use to confirm that they want to leave the page if I remove it.